# Log file not created

Tags: python, logging

I am trying to create a log file as follows:

```
 logging.basicConfig(filename='app.log', filemode='w', format='%(name)s - %(levelname)s - % 
(message)s')
```

the second method is:

```
logging.basicConfig(filename='sample11.log', format='%(asctime)s | %(levelname)s: % 
(message)s', level=logging.info)

 logging.info(str(size_df))
```

size_df is just len(df)

When I was applying this before the logging did work. Would anyone know the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
logging.basicConfig(filename='sample11.log', format='%(asctime)s | %(levelname)s: % (message)s', level=logging.INFO)
```

The logging levels need to be UPPERCASE.